# PDF of the addition of several outcomes from Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We draw $n$ values from a Poisson distribution and add them.

**- What is the expected of this addition**

**- What is the PDF of this addition**

---

It seems quite intuitive to me that if we add $n$ Poisson distributed numbers, the expected value of this addition will just be the $n$ times the expected value of the Poisson distribution. So I expect the answer to my first question to be $n\lambda$. Is it correct?

Is the second question as easy as the first one? The PMF of the additions would just be $n \cdot \frac{\lambda^ke{-k}}{k!}$?

Comment: The answer to the first question is indeed $n\lambda$. The suggested answer to the second question is not even a PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correct. The sum of *n* Poisson random variables, with parameter *k*, say, is also a Poisson random variable with parameter *nk*, **if the random variables are independent**. That is, if X_*i* are independent Poisson random variables with parameter k_i then their sum is also a Poisson random variable with it's parameter being the sum of all the k_i's.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Consider the PGF for this distribution. It is

$$pgf(z)=\mathbb{E}z^X=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\right)z^k=e^{\lambda(z-1)}$$

Then, assuming they are independent, the sum has PGF

$$pgf_n(z)=(pgf(z))^n=e^{n\lambda(z-1)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(e^{-n\lambda}\frac{n^k\lambda^k}{k!}\right)z^k$$

which gives you the probability distribution: Poisson with the parameter $n\lambda$, and you can also check the mean:

$$\mathbb{E}(X_1+\ldots+X_n)=f'(1)=n\lambda.$$